# Does a ViewModel have its own logic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

When assigning ViewModel fields, should the domain objects be passed directly to the ViewModel objects which will then determine how to present the data, or should another class like a service be assigning data from the Model to the ViewModel?

also:

EDIT:is there any sense in dividing a viewmodel into receiver and presenter? (instead of binding only certain fields on update?)

Comment: Think of ViewModels as DTOs :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually the Controller Action takes the business objects and puts whatever is needed by the viewmodel.

If you have a business object that contains the fields Name, Address, Id and the View should only display the Name, then the ViewModel only has a field "Name", and the controller action populates it. The ViewModel should know nothing about your Business Classes, it should only know about the stuff that it needs to display.

The main/only logic is then "Display Logic", that is stuff like "if TotalAmount is negative, display it with CSS Class negativeNumber".

Comment: is there any sense in dividing a viewmodel into receiver and presenter?

Comment: I've got close to no experience with MVP-type patterns, but I don't see much need. As the Controller Action creates the ViewModel, the "Receiver" part should only contain some light validation anyway, and most of your Presenter logic is the actual View Page (YourView.aspx if you use the default WebForms View Engine). If you are doing heavy conditional logic within the ViewModel class, maybe you should extract it out into a separate class (if shared by multiple ViewModels). Really, depends on the situation, but usually ViewModels are VERY lightweight.

Comment: What about if logic to display gender in view. Let say you save M and F in database, and when displayed in view, the logic `if gender.Equals("M") return "Male"; else "Female"` should be placed in ViewModels, Repository or when you mapping it to ViewModels?

Comment: @Willy I'd possibly put that either in the View directly (I'm not against if/then/else in Views) or in a HtmlHelper if it's used in multiple Views ("`GetDisplayGender(string dbGender)`") or in some other helper. I don't think the Repository is the right place, unless Gender is an Enum and you map from "M" to Gender.Male. Also, Localization might put constraints on where to put it. I guess it boils down to: What is the "lowest" level in you app that needs to deal with the Display Name?

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of separation of concerns (SoC), if that logic relates to View, then it is safe to be in ViewModel or even in View itself. However, if it relates to Business or Program, then put it in Controller.

Comment: +1, while ViewModels may often be POCOs, adding view logic to them where needed, as opposed to doing it in the controller, keeps things DRY.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience I've used services to map the Model to the ViewModel.  I don't put logic in my ViewModels.

As an aside, it's probably worth your while to check out [AutoMapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper) to assist you with the mapping.  Definitely helps cut down on writing repetitive mapping logic.